# Left action on of $H$ on $G/K=\{gK\mid g\in G\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K,H\leq G$ be finite groups so $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ and $|G|=|H|\cdot |K|$.

Prove that by moving left action of $H$ on the $G/K=\{gK\mid g\in G\}$ there is only one orbit.

I'm not sure that I fully understand what does it mean "moving left action". How should I prove this theorem?

Comment: I haven't heard the terminology "moving", but I would phrase the question as "prove that the left action of $H$ on $G/K$ via the natural action has one orbit".

Comment: This theorem is most easily proved via a counting argument. If there were two or  more orbits, then $|G|>|H|\cdot|K|$.

Comment: After some time trying to understand how to prove it, I still don't see it.

Comment: Use the assumption that the orders of $H$ and $K$ are relatively prime to show that the stabiliser of any point is trivial.  Then use the assumption $\left| G/K\right| = \frac{\left| G\right|}{\left| K\right|} = \left| H\right|$, together with the orbit-stabiliser theorem, to follow up the suggestion from @DonThousand